# Overwriting the value when pushed

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

[the code replicated here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pfwp8u)

I have replicated my code in above instance my expectation is to get an op:

```
[{"data":[{"val":1}]},{"data":[{"val":2}]}]
```

but my result is

```
[{"data":[{"val":2}]},{"data":[{"val":2}]}]
```

I don't understand why please help me for an in-depth knowledge on this problem

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do with the input and whats the logic to get the output?

Comment: Trying sharing sample input and expected output instead of just code.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here. You can put the code directly into the post here instead of externally linking you know. The main thing that is unclear is what relevance this "clonedData" thing is meant to have to your expected output. You appear to be asking for a basic transform of `[1,2]` into the final form, but you're really taking the long way around to what is essentially a simple "built in" function. Looks just like a simple `map()` to me, but unless you can make your intention clearer I don't see this being received well. In fact just spotted one downvote while writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you were trying to achieve there, but based on the sequence, you will need to make copy of object when `push`ing it :

```
_.forEach([{a:1},{a:2}],function(acombination){
        console.log("acombination",acombination);
        _.find([1,2], function(aheader, headerindex) {
            /*Only for repeat the value*/
                if (aheader == 1) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                      clonedData.data[headerindex].val = acombination.a;
                    }
                }
        });
        var newObj = {};
        newObj = clonedData;
        dataObj.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newObj))); 
       // I stringified and parsed to create a new copy. You were pushing the object and later changing the same object, which changed both the values.
});
console.log("Ss",JSON.stringify(dataObj))
```

Answer (score 1):

A little unsure about the question, but you could try deep cloning "clonedData" before pushing into dataObj array and that should solve the output. I think JS is assign by reference.

instead of

```
var newObj = {};
newObj = clonedData;
dataObj.push(newObj);
```

use

```
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clonedData));
dataObj.push(newObj);
```